# Powermock newbie/NoClassDefFoundError when mocking Apache DefaultHttpClient

Tags: mockito, powermock

I'm new to object mocking, and trying to create unit tests for some legacy code.  I'm trying to use powermock for the first time, and encountering a NoClassDefFoundError on line 69 (      DefaultHttpClient mockClient = mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);) (see trace below).

Can anyone give me a hand and point me in the right direction?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LoginClient.class)
public class LoginClientTest {
Properties props = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream("./src/test/resources/LoginClient/default.properties"));
}

/**
 * Method description
 * @throws Exception 
 *
 */
@Test
public void loginPositiveTest()
        throws Exception {

    DefaultHttpClient mockClient = mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
    HttpResponse mockResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
    StatusLine mockStatusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

    Header[] headers = new BasicHeader[2];
    headers[0] = new BasicHeader("Set-Cookie", "COOKIE-DATA");
    headers[1] = new BasicHeader("Set-Cookie", "COOKIE-DATA-2");

    whenNew(DefaultHttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockClient);
    when(mockClient.execute(isA(HttpUriRequest.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    when(mockResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusLine);
    when(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    when(mockResponse.getAllHeaders()).thenReturn(headers);

    LoginClient client = new LoginClient();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(props.getProperty("user"),
                                            props.getProperty("password"));

    String result = client.getCookie(creds.getUserName(), creds.getPassword());

    System.out.println(result);

    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

}

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$221fdb68
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:521)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:100)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:138)
    at [REDACTED].clients.LoginClientTest.loginPositiveTest(LoginClientTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:307)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to be solved by changing from java5 (IBM Websphere) to Sun/Oracle Java6.